# I get MissingPluginException when trying to do things in background

Tags: android, flutter, audio-service

Most of my background code ends with `MissingPluginException`, I don't know why, but I implement everything as it said;
I tried every possible online solution but nothing works;
now I'm facing it with [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) plugin when I try to play audio from android-home-widget using
[home_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget) plugin;

## minimal code :

```
AudioPlayerTask audioPlayerTask;

void homeWidgetBackgroundCallback(Uri data) async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    if(audioPlayerTask == null) {
      audioPlayerTask = AudioPlayerTask();
      await AudioServiceBackground.run(() => audioPlayerTask);
    }
    AudioServiceBackground.state.playing ? audioPlayerTask.onPause() : audioPlayerTask.onPlay();
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
  HomeWidget.registerBackgroundCallback(homeWidgetBackgroundCallback);
}
```

## Error message:

```
2021-08-12 10:49:25.444 25804-25849/com.******* E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method ready on channel ryanheise.com/audioServiceBackground)
    #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #1      AudioServiceBackground.run (package:audio_service/audio_service.dart:1271:24)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #2      homeWidgetBackgroundCallback (package:*******/main.dart:72:7)
    <asynchronous suspension>
```

## flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1151], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.1)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.58.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

the most plugin with this error is `path_provider` plugin, it never works in the background;

any suggestions, please?

## Edit

github: https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/789

Comment: Provide the Logs of that Exception.

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal see updates

Comment: Ohh it's a flutter issue, sorry I don't know anything about Flutter. I didn't saw the Tag, sorry for that but I hope providing Logs will help someone find out.

Comment: iOS or Android? If Android, you probably didn't follow the Android setup instructions in the README.

Answer (score 0):

just terminate the running process, and do run the app from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Is this is iOS or Android? If iOS, you have to register the plugin's you want to use in order to be able to communicate with the HomeWidget Plugin. This is taken from Home_Widget page - In case of flutter_workmanager this achieved by adding:

```
WorkmanagerPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { registry in
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
}
```

to AppDelegate.swift